# What is the 0 doing in this code?

Tags: javascript

I understand all the code until it hits the zero? why is it needed here?

```
const sum = (function() {
  "use strict";
  return function sum(...args) {
    return args.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  };
})();
```

Comment: 0 is the initial accumulator value

Comment: Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to `reduce()` specifies the initial value. It can literally be anything.

In your example, it is initializing it to `0`. The parameters `a` and `b` are poorly named. Normally the parameters are something more like `result` and `value`, which you could then see you are adding `value` to `result` (which was initialized to `0`).

```js
const sum = [1,2,3].reduce((result, value) => {
  console.log({ result, value });
  return result + value;
}, 0);

console.log('Sum', sum);
```